# Is there way to call a table as a variable in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, rails-activerecord

The title is a bit confusing, so let me explain.

I have 3 Model classes called Table1, Table2, and Table3. All three tables have the "total" column.

**This is what I want to be able to do**:

```
index = either 0, 1, or 2
tableNames = ["Table1", "Table2", "Table3"]
tableNames[index].total
```

^ Obviously I can't do that because tableNames[index] returns a string, not a reference to the actual class itself.

**This is what I'm currently doing:**

```
index = either 0, 1, or 2
if index == 0 then
    Table1.total
elsif index == 1 then
    Table2.total
elsif index == 2 then
    Table3.total
end
```

I guess what I want to do is a bit analogous to the **"send" method** in ruby, where you can use variables as method names.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to do the if elsif check? This makes the code longer and clunkier and I'm wondering if there's a better way. Thanks!

Comment: If `Table1` is your class,  then `Table1.column_name` will raise `undefined method` error, unless you meant that a total is a class method, not the column? Also what is `it` in your current code? We;ll need more context to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the model name as a string. You can do this

```
model_name = "Table1" #or "Table2", "Table3"
model = model_name.constantize 
model.total
```

You can directly turn any string into a class with  `constantize`  method.

Note - If you are going to use rails further, ideally refer to them as Models not tables.